# Cloud Code triggers questions

Tags: parse-platform

I have some questions regarding Cloud Code (Couldn't find details in the docs).

1. Can triggers (afterSave...) trigger other triggers ? Example: afterSave("Post"...) creates a new row in Comments where there's also an afterSave function attached.
2. Is there an afterInsert event ? Or do we need to use beforeSave and check if objectId is null ? Or is there another way to check such thing ? (I need to trigger certain function only after insert, not modification)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The triggers will fire regardless of the source of the change. So afterSave would fire for a row created in another afterSave handler.
2. There isn't an afterInsert; only a afterSave. You can't check if objectId === null in afterSave because it would always be false (it was just saved, after all). You can use [Parse.Object.isNew](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#isNew) to check if it is new. I believe it still returns true in afterSave for a new object.

Comment: Thanks. I changed another trigger to beforeSave and had to use [existed()](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#existed). Your solution lead me to find [this post](https://www.parse.com/questions/difference-between-existed-and-isnew).